# Weird roster group in ejabberd "_root"

Tags: ejabberd

I am trying to debug a weird issue with one user's roster in ejabberd. 
He is having a roster group "_root" show up in his client (PSI).

The server is using mod_ldap for user authentication.

Things tried so far:

- deleting the group from the client -> the group appears again after a while
- unregistering the user with /ejabberdctl unregister user domain.com  -> the group appears again after a while

Only one user is affected by this on the server, which makes me think it has to be something specific to this one user's settings (or client). But we have a bunch of people also using PSI with no problems.

Is there a way to look at the roster groups defined for a specific user in the database directly?

Thanks,
kaza

Answer (score 0):

That "_root" value must come from the roster module data. You did not say which roster module you use, but I guess the server is configured to use mod_roster_ldap and possibly mod_shared_roster_ldap. Check the configuration of the module and explore the content of the LDAP directory to see if you see that value. I would think that value comes from there.

Comment: We're not actually using mod_shared_roster_ldap, but rather just the plain mod_roster and mod_shared_roster , in which we've defined one shared group which works fine. Both configs are empty (ie. default for everything).

Comment: Then it should be the client. Do the user sometime use another client ?